# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=0, data=Intent { }} to activity java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, imageview, android-camera, image-gallery

Here is my code i m writing for opening gallery and camera in my application . App crashes when back btutton is pressed without setting
image. Suggest me solutions to it.

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {

                // this is image view where you want to setimage
                bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                ivKidsProfilePicture.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                childpic = baos.toByteArray();

                Log.d("camera ---- > ", "" + data.getExtras().get("data"));
            }
            masterDatabaseAdapter.insertProfilePicture(childpic);



        }

        else {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            if (bmp != null && !bmp.isRecycled()) {

                bmp = null;

            }

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            ivKidsProfilePicture.setBackgroundResource(0);
            ivKidsProfilePicture.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            childpic = baos.toByteArray();

        }
        masterDatabaseAdapter.insertProfilePicture(childpic);
    }
```

Comment: Problem occurs in the else branch of if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) - if requestCode is not 0 or not RESULT_OK (no photo || back pressed) you still want to get the image.

Comment: but whats the solution to it ?

Comment: In the else branch don't try to get a picture. Or check for nulls e.g. if (data != null) { Uri selectedImage = data.getData(); if (selectedImage != null) { ... } }

Comment: i have tried it but still its not working. suggest some other code please.

Comment: Please point the line where it crashes. Did you remove all code from the else branch and it still didn't work?

Comment: nope i didnt remove any code because in else block  i m opening gallery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54719/discussion-between-user5111-and-margarita-litkevych).